# ASP.NET Session variables only being set 2nd time around

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have three `Session` variables that I assign values to in an `ASMX` web service like so:

```
Session["Stats1"] = items;
Session["Stats2"] = items;
Session["Stats3"] = items;
```

Each assignment happens in its own web method, and when I debug, each one is hit and the 'items' variable is not null. Just as background info, 'items' is a `List` of the following class:

```
public class BindableStat
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
}
```

When I need to cast and use the `Session` variables I do:

```
if (Session["Stats1"] != null && Session["Stats2"] != null && Session["Stats3"] != null)
{
    // stuff
}
```

The problem is, the first time I assign values to and then use the variables, only 'Session["Stats1"]' is not null, the others are null. Assigning the values a second time and any amount of times thereafter produces the expected result: each variable is not null and has the correct value.

`web.config` looks like this:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="120" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Why could `Session` be failing first time around?

**edit:** I've managed to fix the problem by assigning a random value to the Session the first time the page loads (I suppose I could do this the first time the app runs). In `Page_Load` I just set 'Session["x"] = "x";'. I still have no idea why Session needs to be initialized like this.

Comment: Where do you try to get the values from the sessions? in the web-service?

Comment: No, I try get the values in code behind, on a button click handler

Comment: When declaring a WebMethod - do you pass `True` for EnableSession declarative attribute? Can u show a WebMethod declaration?

Comment: Little strange, a web-service usually resides in another web-server and you are trying to read its session values in another server (they both localhosts in your case, but it is still strange).

Comment: Yep I do. Otherwise it wouldn't work 2nd time around. I use '[WebMethod(true)]' for all the methods in question

Comment: I'm using the ws purely for ajax

Comment: did you ever figure out the problem ?